# Get All Keys and Values from Header in Apache Camel

Tags: cors, apache-camel

I am trying to get the header keys and values from response, but I am only able to get the content-type. After googling I found it's because of CORS issues, I tried to add following inside route but still not get desired result.

```
<setHeader headerName="Access-Control-Allow-Origin">
     <constant>*</constant>
</setHeader>
<setHeader headerName="Access-Control-Allow-Methods">
     <constant>POST</constant>
 </setHeader>
<setHeader headerName="Access-Control-Expose-Headers">
    <constant>*</constant>
 </setHeader>
 <setHeader headerName="Access-Control-Allow-Headers">
     <constant>*</constant>
 </setHeader>
 <setHeader headerName="Exchange.HTTP_METHOD">
      <constant>POST</constant>
 </setHeader>
```

I am using spring DSL, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by putting the key of header inside constant

```
<setHeader headerName="Access-Control-Expose-Headers">
    <constant>headerKey</constant>
</setHeader>
```

Comment: I have similar issue of getting passing value in postman into apache camel. I am using REST API POST call. Could you please tell me how to get he value?

Comment: Are you using XML configuration?

Comment: There is no xml concept in my application. I am using direct rest api with spring boot and apache camel

Comment: You need to get the header from your java code and set the required header which you want to expose- like `header.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", headerKey)`

Comment: I am passing pojo values in the format of JSON from postman. In camel routing, when I try to setup headers (setHeader("customer", constant("${body}"))) it is loading proper body data. But, when I try the below line to read only customer id from body it is not working, (setHeader("customerId", constant("${body.id}"))). Any help would be lot of helpful for me.
JSON Data would be look like,
{
 "id":3,
 "name":"Reddy",
 "location":"YSR"
}

Comment: I'm suspecting body is coming as string format, can you try to convert it into json and see?